# Select2: How to apply Margin-Left to Container? Container doesn't have a unique ID

Tags: jquery-select2

When I apply Select2 to my dropdown, it adds a bunch of tags including the outer container:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container 
   select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr">
```

I need to apply a CSS style to this container, but only for this dropdown (not the other Select2 controls!). I need to add a `Margin-Left: 10px` to it. But how to do it when there's no ID from my original dropdown used anywhere? Can I pass or enforce an ID on this container?

The only Select2 elements that reference my unique dropdown's ID start down below, and I don't need to touch any of those.

I also can't do this, there is no margin-left config item:

```
$('#myselect').select2({margin-left: "20px"});
```

I have a JSFiddle here; the goal is to move this dropdown right by 15px. Right now it's not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/g2c9m8aa/5/

**NOTE** I need to do something similar with Disabled Color.
The Disabled Color CSS applies to the Container which doesn't have an ID. But I don't want to do it across the board. I o**nly want to apply the style to this particular Select2 control**.

Answer (score 2):

**use CSS** to set margin of all select2 elements :

```
.select2{
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

or only specific element :

```
#myselect{
  margin-left:200px;
}
```